# combining lines in a txt file in python

Tags: python

I have the following data in my text file.

```
26 #denotes the number of lines to process
01 #LSB1
FF #MSB1
02 #LSB2
FE #MSB2
03 #LSB1
AA #MSB1
04 #LSB2
AE #MSB2
01 
FF
02
FE
01
AA
02
AE
01
FF
02
FE
00 #exclude these lines
01 #exclude these lines
02 #exclude these lines
03 #exclude these lines
04 #exclude these lines
05 #exclude these lines
18 #denotes the number of lines to process
01
FF
02
FE
```

.... and so on

The first line denotes the number of lines to process in the file. In this case it is 26.
So i have to process the following 20 lines of data into a pattern shown below

```
00000026
FE02FF01 
AE04AA03
FE02FF01
AE02AA01
FE02FF01
00000018

#Counter = Line1 - 6
```

Here the first line is filled with trailing zeroes to make it a 32bit data.
The next line is (MSB2 + LSB2 + MSB1 + LSB1).This to be done for the next 20 lines in the text file.
Remaining 6 lines are to be excluded. Then again check the counter from the next line.
In this case it will be 18-6=12.. so process the next 12 lines and skip the following 6 lines.

I have written the following code to save the data in a output txt file.
But i have no idea how to process the pattern part.

```
with open(filename) as fp:
            memArray = [line.strip() for line in fp]
            mem_file.write(memArray[0].zfill(8)+"\n")
            count = int(memArray[0]) - 6
```

If i could get some help or functions to do the data processing it would be easier for me to start with the logic.

Comment: does the file contain those comments ?

Comment: No..i added it here..to explain

Comment: I'm asking for after 26 lines is there any condition for skipping the line because the data in all lines look same.

Comment: Yeah..after 26 lines..my next counter will be (18- 6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(filename) as fp:
    memArray = [str(line.strip()) for line in fp]


    index = 0
    while index < len(memArray):
        count = memArray[index]
        print(count.zfill(8))
        index += 1

        data_count = int(count) - 6
        for i in range(int(data_count / 4)):

            print("".join(memArray[(index + 3):(index-1):-1]))
            index += 4
        index += 6
```

Comment: thanks for this solution..i seperated the data into 2 lists and then used the for loop code that you have provided..works perfectly